# Create JSON String from Array?

Tags: swift

This might be an easy question, but how can I create a simple JSON String from an existing Array?

In the Documentation the only thing I found is:

```
class func JSONObjectWithData(_ data: NSData,
                  options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions,
                    error error: NSErrorPointer) -> AnyObject?
```

But I only want to create a simple JSON String from an existing Array.

With the existing Swift JSON Extensions I am only able to parse existing JSON Strings, and could not create a new String.

I could manually create the String, but there might be a better solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a NSArray object, you could create your JSON String by using something like:

```
func JSONStringify(value: AnyObject, prettyPrinted: Bool = false) -> String {
    var options = prettyPrinted ? NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted : nil
    if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value) {
        if let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(value, options: options, error: nil) {
            if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                return string
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

[I found here the details for this function](https://medium.com/swift-programming/4-json-in-swift-144bf5f88ce4).

### SWIFT 3

```
 func JSON2String(jsonObj: AnyObject, prettyPrinted: Bool = false) -> String {
    let options = prettyPrinted ? JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted : []
    if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObj) {
        if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObj, options: options) {
            if let string = String(data: data, encoding: Task.StringEncoding) {
                return string
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an array of `String`s called `array`. You would do this:

```
let array = [ "String1", "String2" ]
var error:NSError?

let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &error)
let str = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)

println("\(str!)")
```